# Custom attributes are not consistent?

Tags: c++, managed

i have converted a C++ library to managed and get the following error on this code line:

```
std::ifstream fin(filename, std::ifstream::in);
```

Errors:

```
Error 30 error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0003b5). C:\Users\Freeman\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\testsharp1\cpp1\MSVCMRTD.lib(locale0_implib.obj)


Error 32 error LNK2034: metadata inconsistent with COFF symbol table: symbol '??0_Container_base12@std@@$$FQAE@XZ' (06000493) has inconsistent metadata with (0A000075) in MSVCMRTD.lib(locale0_implib.obj) C:\Users\Freeman\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\testsharp1\cpp1\LINK

Error 59 error LNK2034: metadata inconsistent with COFF symbol table: symbol '?memcpy@@$$J0YAPAXPAXPBXI@Z' (060004DD) has inconsistent metadata with (0A0003E3) in MSVCMRTD.lib(locale0_implib.obj) C:\Users\Freeman\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\testsharp1\cpp1\LINK

Error 60 error LNK1255: link failed because of metadata errors C:\Users\Freeman\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\testsharp1\cpp1\LINK
```

How to fix that or how to change that code line without having to change the rest of the code?

Comment: +1 for actually pasting your error here.  Most questioners seem to think "it doesn't work" is a sufficient explanation of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you're compiling your managed code which includes the `<fstream>` header. That means that all declarations from `<fstream>` are compiled as if they're managed, too. Yet the CRT DLL contains unmanaged versions of `<fstream>`.

At link time, this is detected when the import lib `MSVCMRTD.lib` contains the unmanaged `std::_Container_base` class, but your .obj files need a managed `std::_Container_base`.

(The `_C` tells us it's an implementation helper class).

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but after 1 week struggling to solve this I feel committed to post the solution I found to whoever could be fighting with a similar error.

In my case I'd two projects, one unmanaged with std's all over the place (list, vectors and queues, this is a project which should work on linux too so I cannot use .net collections), and pure standard C++ code, on the second project I create a managed project to wrap this classes to be used in .net projects, I was using Visual Studio 2010, trying to use framework 2.0, unfortunatelly VS 2010 does not have a nice support to VC++, and I tried everything to force it to use 2.0, without success, everytime I compiled I got the same annoying message "Inconsistent blah".

I installed VS 2008, ported the projects to 2008 and voila! everything worked in 10 mins, I spend 1 week trying to solve this in VS 2010 and 2008 did the trick.

I hope this might save a lot of hours trying to solve something that appears to be unsolvable on VS 2010.